# How to check if admin user is logged in on frontend

Tags: admin, frontend, session

I was wondering how it is possible to check if admin user is logged in on the frontend?

Comment: A quick google search gave me a couple of old Stackoverflow posts
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831156/magento-detect-if-admin-is-logged-in-in-frontend-pages & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340953/check-on-frontend-if-admin-is-logged-in & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342165/magento-how-to-check-if-admin-is-logged-in-within-a-module-controller

Did you try any of these solutions? As far as I can see there were some accepted answers among them. And don't forget to upvote the answer that solved it ;)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. And nothing works...

Comment: Try `Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::SESSION_NAMESPACE))->start(); if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ...`